# How to get right vertex data on Shipping environment?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

How can I get right vertex data on Shipping environment?

In UE5 development, I want to get vertex data from the UStaticMesh，These code works well on editor environment, I can get the right vertex data. But after packing, they can't work properly on shipping environment. I tried many times, but it always returns some wrong data to me. Someone knows how can I get right vertex data on shipping environment? Only IndexBuffer data is right on shipping environment.

```
TArray<FVector> Vertices;
TArray<int32> Triangles;
int32 LinkGreenFirstLOD = pLinkGreenMesh->GetRenderData()->GetCurrentFirstLODIdx(0);
const FStaticMeshLODResources &lodResLinkGreen = pLinkGreenMesh->GetLODForExport(LinkGreenFirstLOD);
int32 nNumIndexLG = lodResLinkGreen.IndexBuffer.IndexBufferRHI->GetSize() / lodResLinkGreen.IndexBuffer.IndexBufferRHI->GetStride();
Triangles.SetNum(nNumIndexLG);

if (lodResLinkGreen.VertexBuffers.PositionVertexBuffer.IsInitialized())
    {
        // Get Vertex buffer
        const FPositionVertexBuffer& PositionVertexBuffer = lodResLinkGreen.VertexBuffers.PositionVertexBuffer;

        // Get Vertex num
        nLGVertexCount = PositionVertexBuffer.GetNumVertices();
        nIndexSize += nLGVertexCount;
        //Get Vertex data
        TArray<FVector3f> arrLGVertex;
        arrLGVertex.SetNum(nLGVertexCount * PositionVertexBuffer.GetStride());

        FVector3f* LGVertex = (FVector3f*)RHILockBuffer(PositionVertexBuffer.VertexBufferRHI, 0, nLGVertexCount * PositionVertexBuffer.GetStride(), RLM_ReadOnly);
        FMemory::Memcpy(arrLGVertex.GetData(), (FVector3f*)PositionVertexBuffer.GetVertexData(), nLGVertexCount * PositionVertexBuffer.GetStride());
        for (int32 i = 0; i < nLGVertexCount; i++)
        {
            Vertices.Add(FVector(arrLGVertex[i].X, arrLGVertex[i].Y, arrLGVertex[i].Z));
        }
        RHIUnlockBuffer(PositionVertexBuffer.VertexBufferRHI);

        uint16* indices = (uint16*)RHILockBuffer(lodResLinkGreen.IndexBuffer.IndexBufferRHI, 0, lodResLinkGreen.IndexBuffer.IndexBufferRHI->GetSize(), RLM_ReadOnly);
        for (int32 i = 0; i < nNumIndexLG; ++i)
        {
            Triangles[i] = indices[i];
        }
        RHIUnlockBuffer(lodResLinkGreen.IndexBuffer.IndexBufferRHI);
    }
```

or

```
    for (int32 i = 0; i < PositionVertexBuffer.GetNumVertices(); i++)
        {
            FVector3f fv3Pos = PositionVertexBuffer.VertexPosition(i);
            Vertices.Add(FVector(fv3Pos.X, fv3Pos.Y, fv3Pos.Z));
        }
```

Also can't work on shipping environment.